# Docker has no package manager

Tags: docker, curl, apt, package-managers

Using the image [firesh/nginx-lua](https://hub.docker.com/r/firesh/nginx-lua/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated). After running the docker Image I want to install some things but it has no apt / apt-get or any other package manager.

I tried to install apt on the docker but it requires curl, which does not exist as well.

Any solution for that? I cannot install anything manually on this docker

Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the base image used alpine, it has apk, you can use `apk` as `apk` is the default package manager on alpine.  You can add things using `apk add <desired_thing>`, before this also do `apk update`.

Ex: for adding curl:

- `apk update`
- `apk add curl`

Comment: Thanks, actually what I am trying to achieve is luarocks. Using apk add luarocks  I receive OK: 53 MiB in 38 packages. But then luarocks still don't exist: sh: luarocks: not found

Comment: first use apk update, then add things. Not sure, i didn’t try it, you can try once.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to install apt or apt-get with apk? or with curl? apk add apt doesn't work

Comment: apk is the default package manager on alpine. You don't need apt, and using two package manager is not good practice. Btw, I don't know how to add apt by apk.

Comment: Is there a way to change the image base?

Comment: you need to change the Dockefile of `firesh/nginx-lua` image to change the base image (if you have access), basically you need to create new image using the changed Dockerfile, it can only be done if you are the administrator of `firesh/nginx-lua` image.

Comment: What if I create a new DockerFile and use FROM: firesh/nginx-lua?

Comment: you can ask a separate question for this I think, as stackoverflow is suggesting me not to extend discussion in comments.

Comment: I opened a new question. Would you please take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66365340/change-a-docker-base-image