# Change a docker base Image

Tags: image, docker

I am using the Image [firesh/nginx-lua](https://hub.docker.com/r/firesh/nginx-lua). The base image is alpine and it comes with a package manager apt. I would like to run this image with a different base, so the package manager will be apt or apt-get. Is the a way to achieve that if I wrote a new Dockerfile with

```
FROM firesh/nginx-lua

<Define a base image>
```

?

Another solution is to use another Image of lua-nginx with luarocks package-manager buit in. But couldn't find one on docker-hub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker has a concept of multi stage builds which you can see [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

With this concepts, you can use multiple `FROM` in your Dockerfile. Each `FROM` can use a different base image. You need to go through the above doc for learning about multi-stage builds, with this you can use things that you need only in your final image.

As from doc:

> With multi-stage builds, you use multiple FROM statements in your Dockerfile. Each FROM instruction can use a different base, and each of them begins a new stage of the build. You can selectively copy artifacts from one stage to another, leaving behind everything you don’t want in the final image. To show how this works, let’s adapt the Dockerfile from the previous section to use multi-stage builds.

Ex:

```
FROM golang:1.7.3
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=0 /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

Another example with comments:

```
#-------------- building an optimized docker image for the server using multi-stage builds -----------
#--first stage of the multi-stage build will use the golang:latest image and build the application--
# start from the latest golang base image
FROM golang:latest as builder

# add miantainer info
LABEL maintainer="Sahadat Hossain"

# set the current working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# copy go mod and sum files
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# download all dependencies, dependencies will be cached if the go.mod and go.sum files are not changed
RUN go mod download

# Copy the source from the current directory to the Working Directory inside the container
COPY . .

# build the Go app (API server)
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o server .

############ start a new stage from scracthc ###########
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

WORKDIR /root/

# copy the pre-built binary file from the previous stage
COPY --from=builder /app/server .

# Expose port 8080 to the outside world
EXPOSE 8080

# command to run the executable
CMD ["./server", "start"]
```

Comment: That is very useful, thanks a lot. Could you please take a look on this question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66365738/apk-installed-a-package-but-its-not-found-on-docker