# apk installed a package but its not found (on Docker)

Tags: docker, lua, apk

I am using a docker image [firesh/nginx-lua](https://hub.docker.com/r/firesh/nginx-lua) which based on alpine.

I install the package-manager luarocks as follows:

```
/bin/luarocks-3.5.0 # apk update
fetch http://mirrors.aliyun.com/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://mirrors.aliyun.com/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.8.5-66-gccbd6a8ae7 [http://mirrors.aliyun.com/alpine/v3.8/main]
v3.8.5-66-gccbd6a8ae7 [http://mirrors.aliyun.com/alpine/v3.8/community]
OK: 9564 distinct packages available

/bin/luarocks-3.5.0 # apk add luarocks
OK: 53 MiB in 38 packages

/bin/luarocks-3.5.0 # luarocks
sh: luarocks: not found
```

As you can see luarocks was installed, but it is not found when I try to use it.

Any suggestions of how should I install luarocks on this docker?

Comment: check if the binary is really installed and it's in your path. Using `find / -name luarocks` will help to find where is the binary

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski This command shows that luarocks exists under: /bin/luarocks-3.5.0/src/bin/luarocks and /bin/luarocks-3.5.0/src/luarocks. How can I know though if the binary in installed? Should be a file called binary?

Comment: I would assume the file in `bin` is the binary (this is unix convention). To verify it works, try to execute it with the full path `/bin/luarocks-3.5.0/src/bin/luarocks`. If it does, use `export PATH=/bin/luarocks-3.5.0/src/bin:$PATH` and than you will be able to invoke `luarocks` from the shell without the full path

Comment: This is the output after running the path you offered: "env: can't execute 'lua': No such file or directory".

Comment: now the `lua` binary is missing. Do the same search, however this indicates problems with the whole environment. I have tried to replicate your case `docker run -ti --rm --name test  firesh/nginx-lua  sh` but for me even `luarocks` is not installing properly. Do you need to use this image or you can start from standard alpine image and install all the tools you need.

Comment: I managed to install it. First install `lua-dev` package than `luarocks`. This will give you `luarocks-5.1`

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski I rather use this image.. I removed luarocks and then installed lua-dev and luarocks. still getting "No such file or directory". Did you manage to have luarocks package manager on this image?

Comment: see below in the example. It's workin for me on the same image. Just use `luarocks-5.1` instead of `luarocks` or add `alias` as I described below.

Answer (score 3):

I think this image is not the right thing for what you want to do. This is NginX with LUA (for nginx) enabled. The image doesn't contain any `lua` development environment. To use if for lua, install lua first

```
docker run -ti --rm --name test  firesh/nginx-lua  sh                                                                                                                                                / # apk update
fetch http://mirrors.aliyun.com/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://mirrors.aliyun.com/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.8.5-66-gccbd6a8ae7 [http://mirrors.aliyun.com/alpine/v3.8/main]
v3.8.5-66-gccbd6a8ae7 [http://mirrors.aliyun.com/alpine/v3.8/community]
OK: 9564 distinct packages available
/ # apk add lua-dev
(1/4) Installing lua5.1-libs (5.1.5-r7)
(2/4) Installing lua5.1 (5.1.5-r7)
(3/4) Installing pkgconf (1.5.3-r0)
(4/4) Installing lua5.1-dev (5.1.5-r7)
Executing busybox-1.28.4-r3.trigger
OK: 52 MiB in 36 packages
/ # apk add luarocks
(1/7) Installing ca-certificates (20191127-r2)
(2/7) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.39.2-r0)
(3/7) Installing libssh2 (1.9.0-r1)
(4/7) Installing libcurl (7.61.1-r3)
(5/7) Installing curl (7.61.1-r3)
(6/7) Installing luarocks (2.4.4-r0)
(7/7) Installing luarocks5.1 (2.4.4-r0)
Executing busybox-1.28.4-r3.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20191127-r2.trigger
OK: 54 MiB in 43 packages
/ # luarocks
sh: luarocks: not found
/ # luarocks-
luarocks-5.1        luarocks-admin-5.1
/ # luarocks-5.1 --version
/usr/bin/luarocks-5.1 2.4.4
LuaRocks main command-line interface
```

after this you will have `luarocks-5.1` as a command. If you want to use it without the `-5.1` use

```
/ # alias luarocks=luarocks-5.1
/ # luarocks
Warning: The directory '/root/.cache/luarocks' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing /usr/bin/luarocks-5.1 with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

LuaRocks 2.4.4, the Lua package manager
...
...
```